# pasar parámetros de una variable por url

Tags: flutter, dart

```
_launchURL() async {
const url =
    'billpocket://?identifier=2121&amount=$variable&transaction=venta&usertoken=b9cac7478008f232d67974c03b510614c1ce718f8ffab122c18214a6fd6a&email=joksan@hotmail.com&phone=77778825&reference=esta%20es%20una%20prueba';
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
print(url);}
```

tengo un formulario donde el usuario ingresa un `int` o un `String` y ese parámetro la quiero enviar por por mi `const url`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las variables constantes no permiten datos que van a cambiar dentro de la función o método, reemplaza el tipo `const` por `final` o `String` ya que el tipo de dato que pide `canLaunch()` es una variable de tipo `String`.

```
    _launchURL() async {
final url /*String url*/ =
    'billpocket://?identifier=2121&amount=$variable&transaction=venta&usertoken=b9cac7478008f232d67974c03b510614c1ce718f8ffab122c18214a6fd6a&email=joksan@hotmail.com&phone=77778825&reference=esta%20es%20una%20prueba';
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}
print(url);}
```

Comment: Funciono Correctamente, gracias!!